# Does D have anything like Java's Scanner?

Tags: java.util.scanner, d

Is there a stream-parser in D like Java's scanner?  Where you can just go `nextInt()` to fetch an `int` and `nextLong()` for a `long`, etc.

Comment: readf should work for this

Comment: I don't think readf skips over whitespace automatically.  The point is something that automatically uses whitespace as a delimiter and returns tokens one at a time.  readf does neither of those.

Answer (score 6):

std.conv.parse is similar:
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#parse

The example is a string, though it is also possible to use it with other character sources.

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    // a char source from the user
    auto source = LockingTextReader(stdin);

    int a = parse!int(source); // use it with parse
    writeln("you wrote ", a);

    // munch only works on actual strings so we have to advance
    // this manually
    for(; !source.empty; source.popFront()) {
        auto ch = source.front;
        if(ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')
            break;
    }
    int b = parse!int(source);
    writeln("then you wrote ", b);
}
```

$ ./test56
12 23
you wrote 12
then you wrote 23

Comment: This seems like a very tedious way to skip over whitespace

Comment: It could be easily enough put into a function (just remember to take the source as a `ref` argument)

Comment: You could use `std.algorithm.stripLeft`, which is the fairly new generic version of std.string's `stripLeft`. e.g. something like `source = stripLeft!isWhite(source);`.